# Moving a rails form into a separate view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form in my rails 5 app that takes in User data and stores it in a mysql db.

Everything works great. However, I want to move this form into a separate view that does not correspond to its class name/model, controller name and view.

Can this be done by simply rendering the form into a separate view as a partial?

Any advice would be great.

Controller file:

```
class UserLeadsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user_lead = UserLead.all
  end

  def new
    @user_lead = UserLead.new

    @lead_reasons = LeadReason.all.map{ |r| [r.name, r.id] }
    @lead_sources = LeadSource.all.map{ |s| [s.name, s.id] }
  end

  def create
    @user_lead = UserLead.new(user_lead_params)
    @user_lead.lead_reason_id = params[:lead_reason_id]
    @user_lead.lead_source_id = params[:lead_source_id]

    @user_lead.save

    redirect_to user_leads_path
  end

  private

  def user_lead_params
    params.require(:user_lead).permit(:name, :businessname, :phone, :email, :amount)
  end
end
```

Lets say this is UserLeadController, I want to place its form partial into a view inside of my HomeController? Can this be done?

This is the partial, it tells me @user_lead is nil or empty? I cant seem to see how it is?

```
<%= form_for @user_lead, url: user_leads_path, html: {class: 'col-12'}, remote: true do |f| %>
        <div class="col-12 px-0 text-center">
          <h4 class="fl-color-navy">Some heading here</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 progress-container-center">
          <div class="col-12 progress-bar-block">
            <div class="progress-bar">
              <ol class="progress-steps">
                <li class="progress-step step1 current-step" style="width: 0%;"> <span class="count highlight-index"></span></li>
                <li class="progress-step step2 current-step" style="width: 100%;"> <span class="count"></span></li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendering the forms in a partial works fine. Submitting the form will direct the browser to the controller as normal if the view is correct (Presumably `UserLeadsController#create`, question didn't include the view code).

If things like `@lead_reasons` and `@lead_sources` are important to render the view, that is a little more tricky. Of course in simple cases the partial can just do it inline, you could also for example add a helper method that gets those and then renders the partial passing stuff to the `locals` param. e.g.

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def user_leads_form
        lead_reasons = LeadReason.all.map{ |r| [r.name, r.id] }
        lead_sources = LeadSource.all.map{ |s| [s.name, s.id] }
        render partial: "user_leads_form", locals: {lead_reasons: lead_reasons, lead_sources: lead_sources}
    end
end
```

If you wanted it to go back to the previous page in some cases, e.g. for validation errors, you would need to add that, possibly by adding a parameter to the form, or inspecting the `Referer` request header (intentional misspelling!).

If you wanted it to not leave the page at all, then that is getting into client side scripting solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, would this helper go into the controller of where I want to add the partial view?

Comment: Helpers go in `app/helpers` see [`ActionController::Helpers`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) ".

Comment: Thanks I have that sorted but where do I include this Helper file?

Comment: `app/helpers` should be a default directory created and configured for Rails projects, like `app/controllers` and `app/views`.

Comment: Hi yes this is fine I understand this, but where do I include the helper module ? Everytime I load the form I am getting an argument error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

Comment: Must be a mistake in your view file or the parameters you passed to it, its complaining about a function parameter, not a missing module.

Comment: I added the first few lines of the partial. I implemented your helper way of doing this but I'm still getting the argument error in the first line of the form in the partial..

Comment: @user_lead is not set, either pass it through `locals` or create in the view